# Are the Words "About", "Regarding", and "Concerning" synonyms?

Tags: word-choice, american-english

I've just written the following sentence for my academic essay:

> There is no shortage of debate **about** whether individuals should get advice from friends and family when making life-changing decisions.

In this case, is it possible to substitute the word **about**, for **regarding** or **concerning**, without significantly changing the meaning of the sentence? Which option is more formal?

Cambridge Dictionary gives the following meanings for these three words:

> **About**: on the subject of; connected with;
>
> **Concerning**: about;
>
> **Regarding**: in relation to, about;

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As part of your research for this question it would be an idea to check the meanings of the three words and then to supply links to your references.

Comment: @NigelJ, I've included the meanings of these three words on my question, but as you can see, Cambridge Dictionary says that the words Concerning and Regarding are actually synonyms. However, since I am not a native English Speaker, I would like to gain insight on how Americans deal with these words.

Comment: I have added the AmE tag for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that in that usage you could use any of the options and it would work. In this case however, I think that concerning would be the most formal option.